# Least squares coordinate-wise smoothness

Tags: convex-optimization, normed-spaces, least-squares

What is coordinate-wise smoothness
constant $L_i$ for least squares objective:
$$f(\mathbf{x}):=\frac{1}{2}\|A \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\|^{2}$$

We define coordinate-wise smoothness as:
$$f\left(\mathbf{x}+\gamma \mathbf{e}_{i}\right) \leq f(\mathbf{x})+\gamma \nabla_{i} f(\mathbf{x})+\frac{L_i}{2} \gamma^{2} \quad \forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}, \forall \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$$
A is a $m \times n$ matrix, $A=\left[\mathbf{a}_{1}, \ldots \mathbf{a}_{n}\right] \text { with columns } \mathbf{a}_{i}$
where $e_i$ is a standard basis vector, namely e.g: $e_i \in R^d$ is the vector where ith coordinate is 1 and all other are 0.
I seem to fail to get any of the possible answers. I plugged in the objective to the definition of coordinate-wise smoothness, my steps:

$$ ||A(x+\gamma e_i)-b|| = ||Ax + \gamma A e_i - b||$$
$$ ||Ax + \gamma A e_i - b|| = ||Ax-b + \gamma a_i||$$
by triangle inequality:
$$ ||Ax-b + \gamma a_i|| \leq ||Ax-b|| + \gamma||a_i||$$
$$ ||Ax-b + \gamma a_i||^2 \leq ||Ax-b||^2 + \gamma^2||a_i||^2 + 2||a_i||||Ax-b||$$
$$ \frac{1}{2}||Ax-b + \gamma a_i||^2 \leq \frac{1}{2}||Ax-b||^2 + \frac{\gamma^2}{2}||a_i||^2 + ||a_i||||Ax-b||$$

so it seems like it could be $||a_i||^2$ but the last term does not match ith coordinate of the gradient in my opinion so the first definition doesn't hold. On the other hand I found in other textbook that general smoothness constant for least squares is $\lambda_{max}(A^TA)$. Any guidance how to proceed or hint of what I am overlooking would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you expand $ f\left(\mathbf{x}+\gamma \mathbf{e}_{i}\right) - f(\mathbf{x})-\gamma \nabla_{i} f(\mathbf{x})$ explicitly in terms of norms & inner products? It is not too hard to guess the answer by looking at the single variable problem.

Comment: proceeding like that gives me $||a_i||^2$ so the mentioned solution but I can't see how it works for the general result, namely why the gradient is not correct with the last term

Comment: I think you are correct, in general, if the direction is $h$ then you get $h^T A^T A h = \|Ah\|^2$, so you see where the $A^TA$ is coming from. My comment was just that you don't need to make any estimates, you can derive an exact result.

Answer (score 2):

The smoothness parameter w.r.t. the $l_2$ norm is $\lambda_{\max}(A^T A)$.

The reason is that $f$ is L-smooth w.r.t. the $l_p$ norm if and only if $\|\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x})\|_{p,q}\leq L$, where $p,q \geq 1$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. The proof of this Theorem is not very complicated and you can easily find it online.

Since in your case $\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x}) = A^TA$ the result follows immediately. If you wish to look at it "component-wise", then simply look at the $i$-th column of A. Then an individual component $L_i = \lambda_{\max}(A_i^T A_i)$, and clearly $\forall i, \;L_i\leq L$.

Comment: so in general coordinate-wise smoothness constant is a respective coordinate of the global smoothness constant L?

Comment: The coordinate-wise $L_i$ is always bounded by the global $L$ parameter. This is all we can say about the general case.